# How to replace char inside double quotes in android

Tags: java, android, regex, replace

In my Android app, I want to change the value of a String between double quotes. For example, I want to replace `{"txt":` with `{"":`

I have tried the following regex expressions, but they don't work...

```
    String abc=replace(str, "{\\txt\\:", "");
    String abc=replace(str, "{'txt':", "");...,etc
```

Could anyone please offer help with this.

Comment: Do you want to  replace `{"txt"` with `""` (a string containing quotes) or with an empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape each double-quote using a backslash.

Your question is a little ambiguous, so I'll cover the two most reasonable interpretations of it:

---

If you want to replace `{"txt":` with `""` (as stated in your question) then use this:

```
String abc = str.replace("{\"txt\":", "\"\"");
```

With this code the text `{"txt":foo}` becomes `""foo}`.

---

If you want to replace `{"txt":` with the empty string (as implied by your example code) then use this:

```
String abc = str.replace("{\"txt\":", "");
```

With this code the text `{"txt":foo}` becomes `foo}`.

Comment: @ Mark Byers: Excellent..Cool dude

Answer (score 1):

`"{\\txt\\:"` would mean the string `{\txt\`, if you want to match (and thus replace) `{"txt"` use `"{\"txt\":"`